# Change Row Color in Excel Range if condition is met in vb.Net

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, colors

In range "A" to "H" I want to change color when condition in H cell is met. My code work, but it change entire row color if I use this one:

```
    For Each h In shXL.Range("A2:H150").Columns(8).Cells
                If h.Value > 14 Then
                    h.EntireRow.Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(251, 254, 138)
                End If
    Next
```

Or color changed with shift from H to N, when I use this one:

```
For Each h In shXL.Range("A2:H150").Columns(8).Cells
            If h.Value > 14 Then
                h.Range("A1:H1").Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(251, 254, 138)
            End If
Next
```

How to do it?

Comment: Re tags, note that VB.Net is not the same as VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it various ways, such as the following.

In your example `A1:H1` is relative to column H, hence H to N rather than A to H.

```
For Each h In shXL.Range("H2:H150")
   If h.Value > 14 Then
       h.offset(,-7).resize(,8).Interior.Color = Color.FromArgb(251, 254, 138)
   End If
Next
```